# How can i upload images array and thumbnail image both at once using Angular7 and node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, multer, image-upload

I have a `server-side` based on `node.js(express)` in which i have an `api` for adding `BookingItem` in which i am getting images `array` of booked item.

I am doing in server side in `bookingItem.route.js` like this

```
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
destination: function (req, file, cb) {
cb(null, 'uploads/item')
},
filename: function (req, file, cb) {
let customFileName = crypto.randomBytes(18).toString('hex'),
  fileExtension = file.originalname.split('.')[file.originalname.split('.').length - 1] // get file extension from original file name
cb(null, customFileName + '.' + fileExtension)
}
});

var upload = multer({ storage: storage });


router.post("/", log, loggedIn, upload.array("image", 5), addBookingItem);
```

And in my `bookingItem.controller.js` i am saving booking item like this

```
export async function addBookingItem(req, res) {
 let body = parseBody(req)
 if (body) {
   if (req.files) {
     let pictures = []
     req.files.forEach(item => {
     pictures.push(item.filename)
     })
  body.picture = pictures
  }
  if (body.amenityIds) {
  let amenityIds = body.amenityIds.split(",")
  body.amenityIds = amenityIds
}
body.createdAt = Date.now()
body.updatedAt = Date.now()
let itemObject = new BookingItem(body)
let item = await itemObject.save()
if (item) {
  generateResponse(true, "Booking Item" + MESSAGES.ADDED, item, res)
} else {
  generateResponse(false, MESSAGES.CANT_ADD, null, res)
}
} else {
  generateResponse(false, MESSAGES.COMPLETE_INFO, null, res)
 }
}
```

And on `client-side` i am using `angular7` and i am sending pictures from client side like this

```
<input style="display: none" type="file" (change)="onFileChanged($event)" multiple #fileInput>
<button (click)="fileInput.click()" class="btn btn-primary float-left"> Upload Pictures</button>
```

in my component.ts i am doing like this

```
onFileChanged(event) {
    this.selectedPictures = Array.from(event.target.files)
    this.data = new FormData()
    Array.from(this.selectedPictures).forEach((item: any) => {
    this.data.append('image', item)
  })
}
     addVenue() {
this.spinnerService.show()
if (this.selectedAmenities.length > 0) {
  let am = []
  this.selectedAmenities.forEach((item: any) => {
    am.push(item._id)
  })
  if (am.length > 0) {
    this.amenityIds = am.join(",")
  }
}
let tempFor = []
let tempType = []
let tempBookingType = []

this.selectedFor.forEach(item => {
  tempFor.push(item.name)
})

this.selectedVenueType.forEach(item => {
  tempType.push(item.name)
})

this.selectedBookingType.forEach(item => {
  tempBookingType.push(item.name)
})


this.data.append("name", this.addVenueForm.value.name)
this.data.append("checkIn", this.addVenueForm.value.checkIn)
this.data.append("checkOut", this.addVenueForm.value.checkOut)
this.data.append("pricePerNight", this.addVenueForm.value.pricePerNight)
this.data.append("for", tempFor)
this.data.append("bookingType", tempBookingType)
this.data.append("type", tempType)
this.data.append("amenityIds", this.amenityIds)
this.data.append("locationId", this.addVenueForm.value.locationId)

this.appService.addBookingItem(this.data).then((resp: any) => {
  this.appService.showSimpleAlert("Venue", resp.message, resp.success ? 'success' : 'error');
  if (resp.success) {
      this.selectedBookingType = []
      this.selectedAmenities = []
      this.selectedFor = []
      this.selectedVenueType = []
      this.selectedPictures = []
      this.addVenueForm.reset()
      this.spinnerService.hide()
   }
  })
 }
```

This is working perfectly and i am saving images paths in a `mongo` collection. But currently i am sending `bookingItem` images as an array and now i also want to upload `thubmnail` image and `cover` image also. So how can i send 3 types of images separately and get these 3 types of images on `server-side` ?

Comment: Change the value of the form element here: `this.data.append('image', item)`, you can use something like `image-1-bookingItem`, `image-1-thumbnail`, `image-1-cover`, and then increment the number with every new one you're adding. Multer can help you to see which files are which based on the name you uploaded them with.

Comment: i found my answer on `multer` description. I can do this by passing `fields` array in `multer`. Thank you for your help